# Maximum-likelihood estimation of parameter of a distribution function

Tags: maximum-likelihood

**My Problen**:

> A Random variable $X$ has the following distribution function:
> $$
> F_X(x)=%
> \begin{cases}
> x^\theta, &x\in[0,1]\\
> 0, &\text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

We have gotten `x1 = 0.40` `x2 = 0.75` `x3 = 0.95` from three independent trials. Determine the Maximum-Likelihood estimation of θ.

**Solution**
2.39

**My attempt of solving the problem**
L(θ) = x<sub>1</sub><sup>θ</sup>x<sub>2</sub><sup>θ</sup>x<sub>3</sub><sup>θ</sup> = (0.40<sup>θ</sup> 0.75<sup>θ</sup> 0.95<sup>θ</sup>)
f(θ) = ln(L(θ)) = ln((0.40<sup>θ</sup> 0.75<sup>θ</sup> 0.95<sup>θ</sup>))
f(θ) = ln((0.40<sup>θ</sup> 0.75<sup>θ</sup> 0.95<sup>θ</sup>)) = ln(0.40<sup>θ</sup>) + ln(0.75<sup>θ</sup>) + ln(0.95<sup>θ</sup>) 
At this point I usually make the derivative of f(θ) equal to zero to get θ, but when I try to do so I get
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(θ)) = (-0.916291) + (-0.287682) + (-0.0512933) = -1.2552663$$
The θ disappears and I get left with -1.2552663 which is not even close to the correct answer.

**My Question**:
I am clearly getting the wrong answer.
I would be tankful for any help and/or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the question.  the function $x^\theta$ is the **cumulative distribution function**, not the density.  In other words, $$\Pr[X \le x] = F_X(x) = x^\theta, \quad x \in [0,1].$$  As such, the density is $$f_X(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}, \quad x \in [0,1]$$ and this is what you need to use to compute the likelihood:  $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x_1, x_2, x_3) = \theta^3 (x_1 x_2 x_3)^{\theta - 1}.$$  Consequently the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\theta \mid x_1, x_2, x_3) = 3 \log \theta + (\theta - 1) \log(x_1 x_2 x_3)$$ and its critical points satisfy $$0 = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = \frac{3}{\theta} + \log(x_1 x_2 x_3),$$ or $$\hat \theta = -\frac{3}{\log (x_1 x_2 x_3)}.$$  What happens when you substitute the given observations into this expression?

Comment: how do you get fX(x)=θx^θ−1  ??:)

Comment: @AugustJelemson The derivative of the cumulative distribution function is the density; i.e., $$F_X'(x) = f_X(x).$$